# Ajax error when putting in scriptmanager

Tags: ajax

Every time I put the AJAX scriptmanager into an application, I get this error:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Invalid origin: https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net

Does anyone know why this is occuring? In one example I'm not even using any AJAX controls, but still gives me that error. I'm using VS2010.

Answer (score 0):

I have also had this issue in an ASP MVC 3 application. I got around it by changing my default browser to Chrome instead of IE. I think there maybe some integration between IE and facebook that is causing the issue. Anyhow changing my browser to chrome has solved the issue. I'm sure some further tinkering with IE would reveal the exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please disable the ask toolbar from Internet explorer permanently.Same issue occurs for me too.When i disabled asktool bar it works.

This may solve your issue