# jQuery showing error in IE-7

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Invalid origin: 
http://static.ak.facebook.com
```

When i run my MVC3 application on IE-7 it shows me this error in `ticker_37?build=135[dynamic]` file. Can anyone tell me the solution for this problem?

Comment: This does not look like a `jQuery` error

Comment: Well, it's a client-side JS error at least.

Comment: OP: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: But this error comes in ticker_37?build=135[dynamic] dynamically generated file at runtime

Comment: @jimw - client-side JS as opposed to?

Comment: Gabe: As opposed to server-side JS, client-side native, etc. etc.

Comment: OP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723658/ajax-error-when-putting-in-scriptmanager seems to be a very similar problem, sadly without an answer.